# Create TNotifyEvent in C++ for use at Application level

Tags: c++, hook, c++builder

I need to hook on to the Application's `OnDeactivate` event in C++ Builder.  So I need to write my own function to run when the `OnDeactivate` event fires for the application, but I don't know where or how to define that function.

Ideally I would like my code to look something like this:

```
WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
  try
  {
     Application->Initialize();
     Application->OnDeactivate = myFunction;
     Application->Run();
   }
```

later:

```
 void myFunction(TObject *Sender)
 {
 //Do Stuff
 }
```

When I write it like this in my `.cpp` file, it complains

> cannot convert 'void(*)(TObject *)' to 'TNotifyEvent'

If I change my function to return a `TNotifyEvent` (which shouldn't work anyway), it gives me the hilarious error of

> Cannot convert 'TNotifyEvent' to 'TNotifyEvent'

So, how should I go about writing a function to hook to my Application property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign a stand-alone function where a non-static class method is expected instead. You have two choices:

1) Move your event handler into a helper class:

```
class Helper
{
public:
    void __fastcall myFunction(TObject *Sender)
    {
        // ... do stuff
    }
};

WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();

        Helper helper;
        Application->OnDeactivate = &helper.myFunction;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

2) Leave the function as a non-class function, but give it an extra parameter to receive the compiler's `this` pointer, and then use a `TMethod` struct to help you pass it to the event as a suitable `TNotifyEvent`:

```
void __fastcall myFunction(void *pThis, TObject *Sender)
{
    ...
}

WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();

        TMethod m;
        m.Data = NULL; // passed to the pThis parameter, can be whatever you want
        m.Code = &myFunction;
        Application->OnDeactivate = reinterpret_cast<TNotifyEvent&>(m);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

With that said, `TApplication::Run()` will exit immediately if a MainForm is not assigned, so the simpliest solution is to just drop a `TApplicationEvents` component onto your MainForm and then you can assign an `OnDeactivate` event handler to it at design-time.

**Update**: alternatively, if your project has any `TForm` or `TDataModule` objects, you can simply drop a `TApplicationEvents` component on one of them, and assign an `OnDeactivate` event handler to it at design time.  It will then hook into the Application's `OnDeactivate` event for you.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it like that.

What I did was create a TActionList that contains various actions.  I created an action that would be called on the forms OnCreate event with this code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::onCreateActionExecute(TObject *Sender)
{
 Application->OnDeactivate = MyAppDeactivate;
}
```

and then added a little test function to my Form:

```
void __fastcall MyAppDeactivate(TObject *Sender) { ShowMessage("Deactivate"); };
```

and that was it.

Comment: You said that you wanted it called on the **form's** OnCreate event, but I already know how to do that.  I don't want to hook to a Form event, but to an Application event like I said.