# C++Builder Console application: linking to a __closure based method

Tags: closures, console-application, c++builder

First off, forgive me on the title. Not really sure how to ask this question:

I have an application that I need to convert to a console application (note the application runs fine as a VCL style windows app). The app uses a few 3rd party widgets that have callback functions. However, when I attempt to compile it, I get 'cannot convert ...' errors, like this:

> Cannot convert 'void(Tobject *, TErrorEventParams *)' to 'TErrorEvent'

`TErrorEvent` is defined as:

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure* TErrorEvent)(System::TObject* Sender, TErrorEventParams *e);
```

The line causing the error is:

```
handler->OnError = errorHandler;
```

The code for errorHandler is:

```
void __fastcall errorHandler(System::TObject* Sender, TErrorEventParams *e)
{
    memoLine = e->Description;
    updateLog();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a non-class member as an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870540/use-a-non-class-member-as-an-event-handler)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create TNotifyEvent in C++ for use at Application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193174/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `__closure` type is a pointer to a non-static class method.  The compiler does not allow you to assign a standalone non-class function where a `__closure` is expected.  It requires a pointer to a method of a class object.  Karem's answer shows you one way to accomplish that.

However, there *IS* a way to use a non-class function, using the helper [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) struct (which is how a `__closure` is implemented behind the scenes).

First, add an explicit 'this' parameter to your event handler:

```
void __fastcall errorHandler(void *This, TObject* Sender, TErrorEventParams *e)
{
    memoLine = e->Description;
    updateLog();
}
```

And then assign the event handler like this:

```
TMethod m;
m.Code = &errorHandler
m.Data = NULL; // any value you want to pass to the 'This' parameter...
handler->OnError = reinterpret_cast<TErrorEvent&>(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this documentation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Closure

In short:

`TErrorEvent` is defined as a pointer to a class member function. So `errorHandler` has to be declared as a class member function.

The implementation could look somewhat like this:

```cpp
class TMyClass
{
private:
    TMyHandler* handler;
    void __fastcall errorHandler(System::TObject* Sender, TErrorEventParams *e);
public:
    __fastcall TMyClass();
} my_dummy_class;

__fastcall TMyClass::MyClass()
{
    //handler has to be created
    handler->OnError = errorHandler; 
}

void __fastcall TMyClass::errorHandler(System::TObject* Sender, TErrorEventParams *e)
{
    memoLine = e->Description;
    updateLog();
}
```

Comment: Yes that was what I had in mind.  Btw. do not forget to declare at least one variable of the class type otherwise the code would be optimized out completely as unused (I added it to your code already)

Comment: The answer about using TMethod is what I needed. I didn't make it clear that there was no class structure (I thought saying it was a console app would be enough).